# Setup hangfire jobs correctly within an ASPNET Core 2.1 application?

Tags: hangfire, asp.net-core-2.1

Moving to asp.net core 2.1 is breaking our hangfire job setup.

In the `Main` method of `Program.cs` we have something like

```
var webHost = BuildWebHost(args);
ConfigureHangfireJobs(webHost);
webHost.Run();
```

The `BuildWebHost` looks like this:

```
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(ConfigConfiguration)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseApplicationInsights()
    .Build();
```

`ConfigureHangfireJobs` is calling `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate()` which needs the `JobStorage.Current` to be set, and I found it gets set when the hangfireserver middleware is added, while the hangfire service is configured in the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method. As far as I know, middleware setup is to be done in the `Configure` method of the `Startup` class, so that's where we call the `app.UseHangfireServer` which sets the `JobStorage.Current`.

With core 2.0 everything was running fine as the `Configure` method was called during our `BuildWebHost()` method and so the `JobStorage.Current` was then setup and available for the `ConfigureHangfireJobs`. But when switching to core 2.1, the `Configure` is now called as part of the `webHost.Run()` method. Which means our `ConfigureHangfireJobs` now fails because the `JobStorage.Current` is not ready yet.

Now, of course I could setup the hangfire jobs as part of the `Startup.Configure` method, but that's just not where it belongs. An other option would be to setup the `JobStorage.Current` myself, but then isn't that the responsibility of the hangfireserver middleware ?

So my question is: how are we supposed to setup hangfire jobs correctly in core 2.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it working by requesting the JobStorage service like so:

```
services.GetRequiredService<JobStorage>();
```

Even if I don't need a hand on it, it sets the JobStorage.Current.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version of ASP.NetCore 2.1 use

```
      app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<JobStorage>();
```